# VK API - получить id пользователя при наличии access token

Tags: vkontakte-api

Есть access_token пользователя. Каким методом vk api можно получить id владельца этого токена? account.getProfileInfo вроде не подходит

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/users.get

Answer (score 3):

Очень просто, достаточно воспользоваться методом `users.get` к примеру. Если не задать ID пользователя принудительно. Он возвращается ID пользователя через токен которого вы работаете. Ну и в полученном json ответе, будет и id.

p.s Если у вас возникнут еще вопросы по поводу ВК и телеграм, разработки ботов и любой автоматизации, спрашивайте, с удовольствием отвечу на ваши вопросы.